# Error "user-defined type not defined" keep popup?

Tags: excel, vba

recently the "user-defined type not defined" error keep pop up even I just type something in cell. What make it happen? I found out its caused by the below function, but don't know which definition go wrong. `Company` is a `class module`. Thanks

Defined variable:

```
Sub Test()    
    Public com As Company
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim nEndRow As Long
    Dim Id As String
    Dim sidList() As String
    Set com = New Company
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

Comment: Post Type definitions and codes.

Comment: @Harun24HR forgive me cannot post the full code, above is the definition I defined. thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `Public com as Company` be at the top of the module before any procedures?  It would throw an error if used within a procedure?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I put it outside and still the same.